# Apple Pay with magento Getting error

Tags: magento2, error, payment-gateway, server-setup

I implemented apple pay in my magento store I create button and now i want onvalidatemerchant but when I call end point I'm getting this error

> ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unkown ca.

I am implementing apple pay in Magento so far I have implement this code

Answer (score 0):

If the server sends you a TLS alert unknown ca like in this case then the server does not accept the client certificate you have send. The reason for this might be that you have used the wrong certificate or you've used the correct certificate but failed to add the necessary chain certificates.